# Husky robot shows rostopics but not message over them

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, clearpath

I have a Clearpath husky robot setup with their ros noetic image (ubuntu 20.04 on amd64 architecture) `clearpath-universal-noetic-amd64-0.5.14.iso` which to my surprise did not come with ros and other packages pre-installed. So, I installed them (`husky_base, husky_bringup, husky_control, husky_description, husky_gazebo, husky_msgs, husky_viz`) manually. I followed the instructions on http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/noetic/husky/InstallHuskySoftware.html#installing-husky-software till the command `sudo journalctl -u ros`. `rostopic list` gives me the below output.

```
administrator@husky:~$ rostopic list
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/diagnostics_agg
/diagnostics_toplevel_state
/e_stop
/husky_velocity_controller/cmd_vel
/husky_velocity_controller/odom
/imu/data
/joint_states
/joy_teleop/cmd_vel
/joy_teleop/joy
/joy_teleop/joy/set_feedback
/odometry/filtered
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/set_pose
/tf
/tf_static
/twist_marker_server/cmd_vel
/twist_marker_server/feedback
/twist_marker_server/update
/twist_marker_server/update_full
```

But I don't see any message over them as there is no publisher.

```
administrator@husky:~$ rostopic info /husky_velocity_controller/odom 
Type: nav_msgs/Odometry

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /ekf_localization (http://husky:42525/)
```

For the same robot, I have ROS melodic on ubuntu 18.04 (trimmed down version supplied by clearpath) which can echo the same topics easily. The publisher for same topic in the working setup is `husky_node`. I think this is the issue over here but don't know how to fix it. My `COMM` light for noetic setup is RED and for melodic is GREEN.

```
administrator@husky:~$ rosnode list
/diagnostic_aggregator
/ekf_localization
/husky_node
/joy_teleop/joy_node
/joy_teleop/teleop_twist_joy
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
/twist_marker_server
/twist_mux
```

This is the output of `rosrun rqt_robot_monitor rqt_robot_monitor` for noetic setup.

[image: rqt_robot_monitor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you select the Husky option while installing the ISO?  Could you provide the output of `sudo journalctl -u ros`? (It wasn't include in the question).

Comment: Thanks, Please see the screenshots. https://imgur.com/a/47e6DyF For the original question, "Default" was selected. Now, I tried to format the same PC again with "Install Clearpath Robot" option, then after some screens "husky", then after some screens, met with package manager error. I have my ethernet cable plugged in. Output of "sudo journalctl -u ros" isn't possible now as setup is flashed again and stuck at package manager error in screenshot. Please suggest.

Comment: I flashed the iso on pendrive using balena etcher this time instead of unetbootin and it gave me different screen/ options. I also figured out the package manager error and installation went smooth this time. ROS is pre-installed but still after sending the required commands, COMM light is RED (not green). This pastebin contains output of all the commands which I sent. https://pastebin.com/SMzvRij1

Comment: Is the husky connected?  Can you please provide the output of `dmesg`, `lsusb` and `ls -lisah /dev/`.

Comment: Yes, the serial cable is connected. To double confirm this, I restarted the system back into melodic and it can communicate/ move wheels easily. Here are the `dmesg`, `lsusb` and `ls -lisah /dev/` outputs of noetic setup: https://pastebin.com/xEgc69kz

Comment: Looking at those logs, I do not see the prolific adapter connected.  Can you do the same thing for Melodic please?

Comment: Are the Noetic and Melodic computers the same?

The prolific adapter gets picked up as follows:

[    1.783348] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    1.933110] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303, bcdDevice= 4.00
[    1.933115] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.933117] usb 1-4: Product: USB-Serial Controller D
[    1.933119] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.

Comment: Yes, both setups use the exact same PC and cable connections, just SSD is different on which OS is installed. Logs for all 4 commands are present here for working melodic setup: https://pastebin.com/T61grb6Y

Comment: Looking at the Melodic logs, the Husky is connected to `/dev/ttyS1` based on `/husky_node/port: /dev/ttyS1`.  Was that an intentional change?  On the Melodic machine can you check the `/etc/ros/setup.bash` file and see if `HUSKY_PORT` is set?

Comment: That is not an intentional change. All the cables are as it is in both the setups. Thanks a lot @Tony Baltovski . I edited `/etc/ros/setup.bash` to include `export HUSKY_PORT=/dev/ttyS1` , did a restart and COMM went GREEN. I am now able to move the wheels. By the way, I was wondering if we did not have the working melodic setup/ logs, was there any way to figure out this issue/ check the port on which the serial to serial cable is actually connected?

Comment: Generally, the correct cable and udev rule would work out of the box.  `/dev/ttyS1` is a likey an actually serial port on the computer and it would not be default config.  With actually serial ports, it is harder to debug if they connected to the right device.